# Alguém pode me ajudar com a integração do angular 5 com firebase real time?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, angular, typescript

Preciso integrar o banco de dados do firebase a uma aplicação em angular 5. Peguei o código gerado pelo firebase, criei um arquivo firebase config e coloquei ele lá fiz a importação no módulo. Estou com dificuldade de escrever no banco e buscar as informações de lá. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: cara tira a imagem das chaves, se nao qualquer um vai poder ver.

Comment: As chaves são ilustrativas

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2

Answer (score 0):

enviroment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebase: //copiar o objeto de configuração.    
  apiUrl: suaUrl
};
```

app.module.ts

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent       
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),,
  ],
  providers: [AngularFireAuth],//se quiser usar a auth do firebase
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```